# PHAsset to UIImage,

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using this block of code inside a function, trying to request the image from an asset.

```
    var imageFinal: UIImage?

    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.resizeMode = .exact
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true

    manager.requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: requestOptions) { (data, _, _, _) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            imageFinal = image
            print("successfully")
        }
    }
```

The trouble is that doesn't work every time. I wasn't able to understand base on what criteria works or not.

I need the image from asset to be the exact size of the image from photo library.

Thank you

Comment: where do you get `asset` from? maybe the asset details are out of date

Comment: `PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)`, works good, I display them in a collection view, I'm able to see them but when I request the image sometimes works sometimes doesn't. I couldn't isolate the problem, or why for some works.

Comment: just removing this 2 lines of code seems to solve the problem
`requestOptions.resizeMode = .exact
 requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat`